# logstash/elasticsearch failed to parse date field tried both date format [dateOptionalTime], and timestamp number with locale

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, timestamp, logstash

for some reason, logstash (version 1.5) can't process logs with this exception:

*{:timestamp=>"2016-04-26T09:20:12.141000-0400", :message=>"Failed parsing date from field", :field=>"time", :value=>"2016-04-26T09:20:03.520-04:00", :exception=>java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2016-04-26T09:20:03.520-04:00" is malformed at "T09:20:03.520-04:00", :level=>:warn}*

My Time field in json is:

```
"time":"25-04-2016 04:21:06.786"
```

my logstash configuration is:

```
filter {

if [type] == "json" {
   json {
        source => "message"
        }
    date {
      match => [ "time", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSS", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS" ]
    }    
     }
}
```

On Elasticsearch side I see this exception:

*failed to parse date field [25-04-2016 04:48:14.305], tried both date format [dateOptionalTime], and timestamp number with locale []
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "25-04-2016 04:48:14.305" is malformed at "16 04:48:14.305"*

How do I fix this?

Comment: It actually looks that your time field is not being caught and time value is your system time value, that's why it's in this specific format.

Comment: I think you are hitting [this](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/4989) bug.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem; Logstash will happily do its job, but then Elasticsearch would complain with this same error. You can see that '@timestamp' is produced with the correct variable. The key is understanding this sort of error is the bit where it says something like the following:

```
[2020-07-22 12:27:40,814][DEBUG][action.bulk              ] [logs-p03] [logstash-2020.07.22][0] failed to execute bulk item (index) index {[logstash-2020.07.22][logs] ... org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: failed to parse [shibidp_timestamp]
...
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: failed to parse date field [20200722T002739Z], tried both date format [dateOptionalTime], and timestamp number with locale []
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "20200722T002739Z" is malformed at "2739Z"
```

This indicates that the mapping is screwy... let's see:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:9200/logstash-2020.07.22/_mapping
...
"shibidp_severity" : {
  "type" : "string",
  "index" : "not_analyzed",
  "fields" : {
    "raw" : {
      "type" : "string",
      "index" : "not_analyzed",
      "ignore_above" : 256
    }
  }
},
"shibidp_timestamp" : {
  "type" : "date",
  "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
},
...
```

I included shibidp_severity just to show how most (string things) get mapped. The template doesn't include anything that would match shibidp_timestamp, or any of the other fields that get mapped as type "date" with format: "dateOptionalTime"

Fields that get mapped to this (looking at GET http://127.0.0.1:9200/logstash-2020.07.22/_mapping)

- @timestamp
- date
- shibidp_timestamp

This behaviour would appear to be related to dynamic date detection

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-field-mapping.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/mapping-dynamic-mapping.html

In my case, this dynamic mapping caused a bit of a race condition (the first 'shibidp_timestamp' value encountered informs the mapping for that day's index. Let's see the difference:

```
$ (d="2020.07.18"; curl -s http://127.0.0.1:9200/logstash-$d/_mapping | jq -c '.["logstash-'$d'"].mappings.logs.properties.shibidp_timestamp')
{"fields":{"raw":{"ignore_above":256,"index":"not_analyzed","type":"string"}},"index":"not_analyzed","type":"string"}

$ (d="2020.07.19"; curl -s http://127.0.0.1:9200/logstash-$d/_mapping | jq -c '.["logstash-'$d'"].mappings.logs.properties.shibidp_timestamp')
{"format":"dateOptionalTime","type":"date"}
```

This shows the mapping for shibidp_timestamp in two different daily indices. The former is what we get when encounter something that looks like a string; the latter is something we get when it looks like a timestamp (but fails to then parse as a timestamp)

There are a few things you could do to address this:

- use logstash to remove shibidp_timestamp from the incoming JSON that logstash is sending (this might be useful if you've already used the logstash 'date' plugin to convert that to the @timestamp field). This would be effective immediately.
- alter the mapping (template) such that shibidp_timestamp gets explicitly mapped to a string, and wait for tomorrow's index to begin (or delete today's index)
- include 'basic_date_time_no_millis' (to match 20200722T002739Z) to the '*default*'.'dynamic_date_formats' list (also applied at index creation) https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/mapping-dynamic-mapping.html

Answer (score 0):

Your `@timestamp` has offset (timzeone value) and you need to add that to your configuration. Please see this link: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html

- `Z` time zone offset or identity

  - `Z`: Timezone offset structured as HHmm (hour and minutes offset from Zulu/UTC). Example: -0700.
  - `ZZ`: Timezone offset structured as HH:mm (colon in between hour and minute offsets). Example: -07:00.
  - `ZZZ`: Timezone identity. Example: America/Los_Angeles. Note: Valid IDs are listed on the [Joda.org available time zones page](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html).

So your pattern should looks pretty much like that:

`YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`

Comment: I thought that when using the "date" filter then @timestamp is overriden by the value in my "time" field, isn't that the issue? Anyway, I tried using the pattern that you gave me and I still see the same error

Comment: @deezx it is overriden, but you have to specify correct input format so it does not throw errors, which is your case. Actually, I've misread your question, I'll try to investigate more :|